# how to vectorize exponential probability function

Tags: numpy, probability-distribution

I believe code below is somewhat correct implementation of this exponential heatmap function:

[image]

```
def expfunc(image, landmark, sigma=6): #image = array of shape (512,512), landmark = array of shape (2,)
  a= np.sqrt(np.log(2)/2)/sigma # 
  for i in range(image.shape[0]):
    for j in range(image.shape[1]):
      prob = np.exp(-a*(np.abs(i-landmark[0])+np.abs(j-landmark[1])))
      if prob > 0.01:
        image[i][j] = prob
      else:
        image[i][j]= 0
  return image
```

My questions are:

1. How could I vectorize this code?
2. This probability function gives values to all pixels so how should proceed with very small values? Now I am using threshold of 0.01 for zeros?

Comment: Just to mention, I believe you should change `image` to `x` in the function arguments definition.

Comment: Yes, I changed it

Answer (score 1):

Let me know if this works for you:

```
i = np.arange(image.shape[0])
j = np.arange(image.shape[1])
prob = np.exp(-a*(np.abs(i[:,None]-landmark[0])+np.abs(j-landmark[1])))
image = np.where(prob>0.01, prob, 0)
```

First compute the array `prob` for all of the indices i and j. Then `prob` has the same shape as `image`, and you can redefine `image` based on the values of `prob` using numpy.where.